# error: cannot find symbol class C ERROR? Android

Tags: android, exoplayer

[image: Error screenshot]After updating Android Studio I see an error in exoplayer library. I am attaching the screenshots, If you know anything about this unusual error.

**UPDATE**: I added build.gradle file of both app level & project level

I encountered this problem after I restarted my laptop. I am using a mac book. I found an android update & I see this error after the update.

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.LoadControl;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DefaultDashChunkSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.DefaultSsChunkSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.smoothstreaming.SsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
```

**Here is the project gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.0"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT : Highly recommended to keep the library version
Be careful when update dependencies, different library version may caused error */
ext {
    supportlib_version = '27.1.1'
    gps_version = '12.0.1'
    retrofit_version = '2.3.0'
    exoplayer_version = 'r2.5.4'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is the App gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$gps_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$gps_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$gps_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add gradle implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'

Comment: already added 
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:$exoplayer_version"

Comment: no... actually program is error-free till afternoon, I see this error after some android studio update

Comment: delete build folder and try to sync project again

Comment: Hold on, Let me try

Comment: same issue, I tried

Comment: update app gradle and project gradle in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202007/discussion-between-chandramouli-poreddy-and-ganesh-pokale).

Comment: Any solution? I run into same problem with Android Studio 4, exoplayer 2.6.0

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same issue.